# Open pdf file in intent when click text view

Tags: android-intent

I am creating a messaging app and I have to send a pdf file in it so when the pdf intent opens the user selects a pdf file and then I set a text view '''textview.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE):''' so when I click the text view i want to open the pdf file the user selects

Code

```
textview.setvisibility(View.GONE);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType(application/pdf);
startActivityForResult(intent, 28);
textview.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Now I want to open the pdf in the device's installed pdf application when the user clicks the text view

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @taylor.2317 Ok

Comment: @taylor.2317 Done, now please solve it